# Manual synchronization between Context and Database using EF Codefirst

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using EF 5.0 (CodeFirst) with VS 2012. I changed my model (entity) and manually changed my database. I try to run the application and the following error appears:

> The model backing the 'XXXContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

My only change was the name of the entity property (column in the database).

1. Its automate or ignore the synchronization? For the same has been done manually, only the application that does not recognize it. Or run something that validates manual synchronization.
2. Where is the recorded synchronization information for the application to know that there was a change?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using EF code first, then you shouldn't be changing anything in the database directly, you have to let the models (and code) drive the database design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the option of using Database Initializers or Migrations. In your application startup you can enable initializers with the following:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContextType>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges());
```

You can also subclass and create your own logic if needed. See http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm for more info.

You can also enable migrations and let them automatically update your database. Running `Enable-Migrations` in the Package Manager Console does this. Look here for more information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I used: 
>System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContextType>(null)
So the application envisioned that the model and the database already synchronized.